# Visual Studio 17.4.x and 17.5.x fails to compile Android Dynamic Shared Library Project (C++)

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, msbuild, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a project in a solution that compiles fine in Visual Studio 17.3.4 but that fails compile in Visual Studio 17.4.x and 17.5.x. I am using Windows 11. The solution is the following:

https://github.com/hyvanmielenpelit/GnollHack

Build instructions are here:

https://github.com/hyvanmielenpelit/GnollHack/wiki/Build-Instructions-for-Android-Version-on-Windows

The solution has a **Dynamic Shared Library (Android)** project in C++ called **gnollhackdroid**, which compiles into a .so library. When I try to rebuild the project, it first fails to compile, because there is no NDK installed (even though it should be). After manually installing Android NDK (any version) and setting the right path in Cross-platform C++ Options, the project fails to compile with the following error message (using ndk-r16b here):

```
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lm
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lc
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -llog
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -landroid
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -ldl
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lc
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -ldl
6>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find crtend_so.o: No such file or directory
6>clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
6>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Android\3.0\Android.Common.targets(125,5): error MSB6006: "clang.exe" exited with code 1.
6>Done building project "gnollhackdroid.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

If you look at the reported targets file, the MSBuild command in question is:

```
<ClangLink BuildingInIDE = "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"
           GNUMode="$(GNUMode)"
           ClangVersion="$(ClangVersion)"
           MSVCErrorReport="$(MSVCErrorReport)"

           Sources="@(Link)"
           AdditionalLibraryDirectories="%(Link.AdditionalLibraryDirectories)"
           AdditionalOptions="%(Link.AdditionalOptions)"
           AdditionalDependencies="%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)"
           FunctionBinding="%(Link.FunctionBinding)"
           ForceSymbolReferences="%(Link.ForceSymbolReferences)"
           GenerateMapFile="%(Link.GenerateMapFile)"
           GccToolChain="$(GccToolchainPrebuiltPath)"
           IncrementalLink="%(Link.IncrementalLink)"
           IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries="%(Link.IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries)"
           LibraryDependencies="%(Link.LibraryDependencies)"
           LinkDLL="%(Link.LinkDLL)"
           NoExecStackRequired="%(Link.NoExecStackRequired)"
           DebuggerSymbolInformation="%(Link.DebuggerSymbolInformation)"
           OptimizeForMemory="%(Link.OptimizeForMemory)"
           OutputFile="$(LinkOutputFile)"
           Relocation="%(Link.Relocation)"
           SharedLibrarySearchPath="%(Link.SharedLibrarySearchPath)"
           ShowProgress="%(Link.ShowProgress)"
           Soname="%(Link.Soname)"
           Sysroot="$(SysrootLink)"
           TargetArch="$(ClangTarget)"
           UnresolvedSymbolReferences="%(Link.UnresolvedSymbolReferences)"
           Version="%(Link.Version)"
           VerboseOutput="%(Link.VerboseOutput)"
           WholeArchiveBegin="%(Link.WholeArchiveBegin)"
           WholeArchiveEnd="%(Link.WholeArchiveEnd)"

           MinimalRebuildFromTracking="%(Link.MinimalRebuildFromTracking)"
           TrackFileAccess="$(TrackFileAccess)"
           TrackedOutputFilesToIgnore ="@(LinkTrackedOutputFilesToIgnore)"
           TrackerLogDirectory="$(TLogLocation)"
           TLogReadFiles="@(LinkTLogReadFiles)"
           TLogWriteFiles="@(LinkTLogWriteFiles)"
           ToolExe="$(ClangToolExe)"
           ToolPath="$(ClangToolPath)"
           ToolArchitecture="$(LinkToolArchitecture)"
           TrackerFrameworkPath="$(LinkTrackerFrameworkPath)"
           TrackerSdkPath="$(LinkTrackerSdkPath)"
           EnableExecuteTool="$(ClangEnableExecuteTool)"
>
  <Output TaskParameter="SkippedExecution" PropertyName="LinkSkippedExecution" />
</ClangLink>
```

Apparently ClangLink is failing for some reason. Is there something that I can do to make it compile? The compilation problem started with Visual Studio 17.4.0 and continues to be there in Visual Studio 17.5.1.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This issues seems to be fixed in Visual Studio 17.5.3.